# Converting a list of strings of numbers to tuples with integers Python3

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

Example:

I have a file named `data.txt` saved on my system. This file contains information like:

```
'Noah,14,233,66,21,88,42'
'Robert,34,11,667,2,785,23'
'Jackson,85,22,73,12,662,5'
```

and so on,

My question is how can I make this a tuple with integers?, so this would be desired:

```
('Noah', [14,233,66,21,88,42] ),
('Robert', [34,11,667,2,785,23] )
```

I assume you must use a for loop for each line but I can't figure anything out.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you want a tuple? The format of your data seems like it matches the idea of a collection of key/value pairs which is what a `dict` in python does. Where the names could be the keys and the list of numbers be the value for each key in a dict.

Comment: Also do you have any code currently that loads the `data.txt` file and read the lines? If so it might be helpful to include that in your post so we can see how you are doing that in case something with that is messing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
   with open(data.txt, 'r') as f:
        lines = [(line.strip().split(',')[0], line.strip().split(',')[1:])for line in f]
   print(lines)
```

It will return a list of tuple in the format that you described.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, this is exactly the way I was looking for it to be done! Amazing, thank you very much!

Comment: You can upvote my answer and click on the check mark beside it to mark your question as answered.

Comment: this answer used `split()` function twice on the same string which is unnecessary, check my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly the same output you mentioned, you can split each line on `,` and store it in a tuple,

```
x = 'Noah,14,233,66,21,88,42'
# split string on , 
x = x.strip().split(',')
# x[0] is name, while x[1]....x[n] are numbers
y = (x[0], x[1:])
print(y)
```

Outputs,

```
('Noah', ['14', '233', '66', '21', '88', '42'])
```

Obviously you would need to read each line from file separately first, so,

```
with open("file_name", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
      line = line.strip().split(',')
      output = (line[0], line[1:])
```

will output,

```
('Noah', ['14', '233', '66', '21', '88', '42'])
('Robert', ['34', '11', '667', '2', '785', '23'])
('Jackson', ['85', '22', '73', '12', '662', '5'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with others that a dictionary might be best for this circumstance, but this should achieve your goal:

```
data= """Noah,14,233,66,21,88,42
Robert,34,11,667,2,785,23
Jackson,85,22,73,12,662,5"""

[(row.split(',')[0], row.split(',')[1:]) for row in data.split('\n')]
```

#### Output:

```
[('Noah', ['14', '233', '66', '21', '88', '42']),
('Robert', ['34', '11', '667', '2', '785', '23']),
('Jackson', ['85', '22', '73', '12', '662', '5'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text is exactly as you have it in the question:

```
import re

input = """
'Noah,14,233,66,21,88,42'

'Robert,34,11,667,2,785,23'

'Jackson,85,22,73,12,662,5'
"""

lines = re.findall("'.*'", input) # Find lines which contain text between single quotes

tuples = []

for line in lines:
  line = line.replace("'", "").split(",") # Remove single quotes, split by comma
  tuples.append((line[0], line[1:])) # Add to tuple

print(tuples)
```

Which would print:

```
[
  ('Noah', ['14', '233', '66', '21', '88', '42']), 
  ('Robert', ['34', '11', '667', '2', '785', '23']), 
  ('Jackson', ['85', '22', '73', '12', '662', '5'])
]
```

First we grab all the lines which has something between two single quotes. Then take out the single quotes and create an array by splitting it by the commas. Finally create a tuple with the first element and the sub-array of the second to the last element.